# Assigning objects in Java

Tags: java, object

I have code like this:

```
this.elements = elements;
```

Where `elements` is a `List`. Is the list copied or is it just pointer copy and both will represent the same list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's another *reference* and both represent the same list. In java the notion of pointer is hidden to the programmer. It's the JVM only that deals with the pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Both this.elements and elements are just identifiers for the same list, it won't be copied

Answer (score 2):

Both will represent the same list, all objects in Java are references and are passed as such so modifying an object modifies via the reference.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it will only copy the reference. If you wish to copy the actual list, you will have to call the `clone()` method:

```
this.elements = elements.clone();
```

Note: whether this has the desired effect or not still depends on what the objects in the list are, as they themselves may be references to mutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially a "pointer copy." The proper nomenclature in Java is *reference*, not *pointer*. An essential distinction is that the value of a Java reference is not a memory address, it points directly to an object in the JVM heap.

If you want a copy you have several options, but arguably the best is:

```
this.elements = ImmutableList.copyOf(elements);
```

This technique uses [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) to create a list that cannot be changed. If you want a list that you can modify, do this instead:

```
this.elements = Lists.newArrayList(elements);
```

There's also the "built-in" `clone()` method, but [that has a few pitfalls to watch out for (Effective Java, 2nd ed., Item 10)](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf).